# Starting C++ in VS - Build succeded but no output

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Coming from web development I have been trying to get familiar with compiled programming, specifically C++. I usually run into issues like this and end up getting frustrated and putting it off for another month. Hopefully this is something simple.

I used a basic Hello World script:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Which when I build I get the following with no "Hello World" output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Hello World, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 3/29/2011 10:17:23 AM.
1>PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "c:\users\jeff\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Hello World\Debug\".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\Hello World.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  HelloWorld.cpp
1>LinkEmbedManifest:
1>  Hello World.vcxproj -> c:\users\jeff\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Hello World\Debug\Hello World.exe
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\Hello World.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Debug\Hello World.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.47
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Which seems like it should be working :/

EDIT: :( Of course I just needed to run it. Should the cmd stay open? It just flashes away for me and I get this in my output:

```
'Hello World.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Hello World.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Hello World.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

EDIT 2: Adding cin.get(); has it displaying now, thanks guys...I'm sure it won't be long before I'm back

Comment: First you *build* your executable, then you *run* it to see what it does.

Comment: There are options to have VS download debug symbols for the system DLLs, if you should need them. Until then, just ignore those messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place `cin.get();` before the `return 0` statement. That should let you see the output.
Or navigate to the directory of the executable from Command Prompt and run the **Exe**.

Or click on the green button where it says `Debug`, that should do the job as well.

```
'Hello World.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

This is normal. It's telling you you don't have symbols installed for the system libraries. This isn't a problem, you can still debug your own code.

Debug--> Options and Settings --> Debugging --> Symbols

Comment: +1 C++ is completely unforgiving about not explicitly stating things, like, uh, you have to ask the user to "Press any key to continue", lest you want the program to automatically finish and close before the user can see anything.

Comment: @Eduardo:: The Questioner is going to have loads of fun with C++ specially since he comes from as he says *"Coming from web development I have been trying to get familiar with compiled programming.."*

Comment: Indeed. Trying C++ after being used to programming in an interpreted (or bytecode-compiled) language is like trying OpenOffice or iWork after being used to doing accounting using Excel + huge macros. Only more frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it looks like you have *built* the program but haven't actually run it. Click the green play button and you will likely see a command prompt flash with the output "Hello, World!"

Comment: Bah, of course something that simple. When I run it I do get the command prompt open and close quickly, and I get these messages: 'Hello World.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Hello World.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Hello World.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Answer (score -1):

It's so simple. Simply write `system ("pause")` before `return 0;` code.